# Check in to the current version in Alfresco

Tags: java, alfresco

Is it possible to checkin/upload the document(with versionable aspect applied) without increasing the version number in Alfresco ?

Any kind help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming what you want is disabling automatic versioning, there are a few options available:

1. You can set the property values `cm:autoVersion` and `cm:autoVersionOnUpdateProps` to `false`.
   You can either set the defaults to `false` in `contentModel.xml`, or just set them to false explicitely after the aspect is applied. With these values set to false, alfresco will no longer increment the version automatically. Have a look at http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Versioning_Behaviour
2. You can disable automatic versioning for a node in one transaction regardless of the autoversion* property values using one of the `disableBehaviour` methods of `org.alfresco.repo.policy.BehaviourFilter` (bean policyBehaviourFilter), e.g.
   `behaviourFilter.disableBehaviour(nodeRef, ContentModel.ASPECT_VERSIONABLE);`
3. You can applying the aspect `sys:temporary` to a node to disable autoversioning. This behaves just as 1., but has some other effects as well, e.g. bypassing the archive store on removal IIRC.

If in doubt, try 1. first.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete a version with versionService.

Here's the java doc:

http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/service/cmr/version/VersionService.html#deleteVersion(org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef,%20org.alfresco.service.cmr.version.Version)